# Syntax Error in INSERT TO STATEMENT

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

```
Dim ProductID As String = DataGridView2.Rows(Newewew).Cells(0).Value
Dim BuyPrice As Decimal = DataGridView2.Rows(Newewew).Cells(2).Value
Dim SellPrice As Decimal = DataGridView2.Rows(Newewew).Cells(3).Value
Dim ProductCount As Decimal = DataGridView2.Rows(Newewew).Cells(4).Value
Dim Command3 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
Data = "insert into ProductReceiptDetails" &"(receiptID,Product ID,ProductCount,BuyPrice,SellPrice) " & "values " & "(:0,:1,:2,:3,:4)"

Command3.Connection = Newconnection
Command3.Transaction = NewTransac
Command3.CommandText = Data
Command3.Parameters.AddWithValue(":0", receiptID)
Command3.Parameters.AddWithValue(":1", ProductID)
Command3.Parameters.AddWithValue(":2", ProductCount)
Command3.Parameters.AddWithValue(":3", BuyPrice)
Command3.Parameters.AddWithValue(":4", SellPrice)
Command3.ExecuteNonQuery()
Command3.Dispose()

' ...

Dim Data As String = "INSERT INTO ReceiptDetails (ReceiptDate,ReceiptTotal) " & "values " & "(:0,:1)"
Dim Command As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
Command.Connection = Newconnection
Command.Transaction = NewTransac
Command.CommandText = Data
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue(":0", Now.Date)
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue(":1", TextBox4.Text)
Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Can you help me with this Error?  I'm using VS 2008 and MS Access 2013.  All of the table and column names are correct but it always get an error.

Comment: You should know that using a DAtaTable and DataAdapter, none of that code is needed.  The DB provider objects can do all the work.

Answer (score 0):

Try with brackets and proper spacing and question marks:

```
Data = "insert into ProductReceiptDetails (receiptID,[Product ID],ProductCount,BuyPrice,SellPrice) values (?,?,?,?,?)"
```

and use `Command3.Parameters.Add("@parameter0", ..)` to specify data types.

Comment: Indeed.  The colon prefix is for Oracle I think, or maybe it's MySQL.  One of the two, but definitely not Access.